# How to fill the variables in html template in django?

Tags: html, django

I want to pass "name" to html file and get the response instead of rendering the page. I want to send this html page via email after adding the "name".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<var>{{name}}</var>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the django views code:

```
def sending(request):
    -- passing request.user --
    return_page = html_page(request.user)
    send_email(--email content--)
```

Can someone suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use django render_to_string here.

Ex :

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
rendered = render_to_string('my_template.html', { 'foo': 'bar' })
```

Comment: Great , accept and close. @VaibhavSingh You can create a new function that takes in a template name and sends email.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh how is that *not* "rendering the HTML"? It's exactly that; `render_to_string` is the appropriate thing to use.